# Error message "module '__main__' has no attribute '__package__'" in Flask

Tags: python, flask

just a basic code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def Page(): 
    return 'This is a test'

app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run this, I get the message: `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__package__'`

(it all has to do with `debug=True`)

I know I can start Flask in debug mode by set `FLASK_DEBUG=1` in cmd. But the error message annoys me because I have no clue where it comes from and how to solve it :-)

Thx
Peter

Comment: Please post the entire error message including stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:`app.debug = True`
instead or `app.config['DEBUG'] = True`